# function doesn't work with data copy, while trying to clean nans with that function

Tags: python, function, data-cleaning

def fillnan_mad(df,name):
'''fills columns with median of features_train data set'''
df.loc[:,name] = df.loc[:,name].fillna(features_train.loc[:,name].mad())

def clean_data2(df):
copy = df.copy()
fillnan_mad(copy,'AveragePrice')
roundh(copy,'AveragePrice')
return copy

def clean_data3(df):
fillnan_mad(df,'AveragePrice')
roundh(df,'AveragePrice')
return df

clean_data2, doesn't replace Nan with median. Clean_data3 does. I don't know where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

def fillnan_mad(df,name):
'''fills columns with median'''
df.loc[:,name] = df.loc[:,name].fillna(features_train.loc[:,name].median()) worked well.
mad is not for the median. mad is the mean absolute deviation

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).